# Whitelist outbound traffic in VPC to changing IPs

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, amazon-vpc

I'm working with EC2 servers in a VPC where we'd like as little outbound traffic as possible, and for all outbound traffic to be explicitly whitelisted. However, based on EC2 security groups or network ACLs, it looks like I need to specify the exact IP addresses that are allowed. (The alternative, allowing all IPs on a given port, is something I'd like to avoid.)

A good number of 3rd party services have IP addresses listed - New Relic, for example, lists them at https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/networks.

However, a good number of them don't - I've been having trouble finding the equivalent for Ubuntu repositories, for example, and that's probably because they rotate IPs. (I can't seem to find the IP addresses for Google APIs either.)

I was hoping someone could either 1) tell me I'm wrong, and point out a way of keeping egress-whitelisted IPs in sync with their DNS resolution, or 2) explain how outbound traffic is usually filtered in a relatively secure/paranoid VPC.

Do you usually just whitelist the needed ports, and not bother going to the granularity of IPs? Is there a popular firewall / NAT software that you use for more sophisticated filtering?

I hope this question was concrete enough - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> and for all outbound traffic to be explicitly whitelisted

All outbound traffic from an instance is explicitly whitelisted on AWS per default.

> in a VPC where we'd like as little outbound traffic as possible,

Without knowing any more details about the role of your instances for the rest of your infrastructure, this is what I can envision happening.

You could: 
A. use a topology with a public and private subnet. Instances with mission-critical security and/or compute-instances would run in the private subnet and be only accessible to a management instance on their private IPs.

B. You could make instances on your private subnet accessible on the outside using VPN.

C. If these are Internet-facing servers, you could disallow all outbound connections to any IP whatsoever except for their primary services (Dovecot, NGINX etc.), and use Puppet for automated upgrades (from a repository downloaded to your VPC by your management instance). This way you would not need to worry about the IPs of some mirror repositories, you simply prohibit all of them until verified, and run automated updates for minimal effort.

Hope this helps (and if it does, please vote).

> Is there a popular firewall / NAT software that you use for more sophisticated filtering?

A couple of security companies sell their solutions on the AWS Marketplace (such as country blockers) for those of us who need paranoid security.

Comment: So the option in A is actually what I'm using - outbound connections from the private subnet are through a NAT, which we need for certain reporting services. The problem, though, is when you say "you could disallow all outbound connections to any IP whatsoever except for their primary services" it's not always clear what the IP is! Some services use fixed IPs, but others don't, and it seems very fragile to constantly nslookup and update things...

Comment: You can obtain the information you need using netstat. (nslookup can be very misleading, it has been deprecated for a while and should not be used. You can use dig or host instead.)

Comment: (I do use `dig` usually, for weird some reason I tend to use `nslookup` as a general verb...) The problem here is that the IPs these services use constantly rotate, so wouldn't I have to continuously update? And I feel like I'd only know to update when something breaks...